# Dissociative identity disorder and Coventry

Tags: story-identification, psychology

I read this story at least 10 years ago, but it might be older than that. I don't remember whether it was a full novel or a novella, but I think it was "too rich" to be a short story or a novelette.

It was about a person suffering from a very severe dissociative identity disorder, with a large number of personalities.

The reason the story was considered SF&F is that contrary to usual DID (if it really exists, this being controversial in "our" world) where each personality has no knowledge of the others, the many personalities did interact in the characters's mind. A sizable part of the story takes place "inside the skull" of that character, but probably not all of it. I think I remember also interactions with other characters, psychiatrists and/or psychologists, maybe other DID characters with less severe conditions.

I don't remember many details. I think that some personalities were male and other ones were female. I don't remember the gender of the body. But one point is really very clear in my memory, because of the peculiar use of the word "Coventry", which I had to look up.

One of the personalities was such a dangerous criminal that all the others united to prevent him (yes, that one was male, I am sure) to "take over" the body of the person and they called this "sending him to Coventry". It is not clear how they manage to do that.

At some  point in the story, there is an "outside the mind" crisis, and IIRC, the many personalities had to call the criminal one for help, while still trying to prevent him from taking over, but out of "Coventry" (or else some other personality, possibly a female one, went to "Coventry" to meet him and ask for advice, I'm not sure).

This was a very, very weird story, with so much of it "inside" the mind of a DID person...

This story is definitely not "Coventry" by Heinlein. Here Coventry is not a **real** place, but a "place inside the mind" of a DID character.

Comment: For context: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Send_to_Coventry 'To send someone to Coventry is an idiom used in England meaning to deliberately ostracise someone.'

Comment: @OscarCunningham Well, I did find it out when I first read that book,decades ago. It is just that I hadn't heard that idiom beforehand, though I believed at that time that I was reasonably fluent in english (which is not my first language). Since then I found out that there are many, many more idiomatic expressions to discover.

Comment: If it helps, I think most people from the UK wouldn't know this either.

Comment: “contrary to usual DID (if it really exists, this being controversial in "our" world) where each personality has no knowledge of the others, the many personalities did interact in the characters’s mind. A sizable part of the story takes place ‘inside the skull’ of that character, but probably not all of it.” Many of those who seem to have DID describe experiences very much like this. (Some portion of that population even goes as far as objecting to the “disorder” designation for this experience.) You are correct about the uncertainty here, but the rest of your sentence isn’t quite accurate.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Set This House in Order](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/71847.Set_This_House_in_Order) by Matt Ruff.

[image: Set This House in Order]

The protagonist is *Andy Gage*. He was an abused child and his personality shattered into dozens of separate personalities.

The bad personality who was sent to Coventry is *Gideon*.

All this takes place in Andy's head so as you say *Coventry* is a region in Andy's psyche not a real place. It is described as an isolated island in the middle of a lake.

> Today I wasn't in that much of a hurry, even though I knew that the others were all waiting for me. I stood on the hilltop for a while, staring out across the lake. Inevitably, my gaze was drawn towards Coventry, the lake island where Gideon was imprisoned. There wasn't much to see: a mist had risen from the deep waters in the middle of the lake, reducing the island to a vague outline.

Comment: Yes !!! Indeed, I thought I remembered the "lake", but I was not sure and did not want to put an incorrect detail. But this is definitely the book I was looking for.

Comment: Any chance this book was inspiration for the movie *Split*? There are definitely some significant differences, but there are also enough similarities to make me wonder.

Answer (score 5):

I have a feeling this book could be [Macroscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macroscope_(novel)) (1969) by Piers Anthony.

*Macroscope* is SF, the main character (named Ivo) has more than one personality, one of which (named Schon) committed a severe crime as a youth and was judged and sentenced to isolation as a hidden personality in Ivo's mind by the other super-genius youths in the creche where they were being raised and educated.

The story arc presents Ivo with a dangerous mystery to solve, which tempts him to allow Schon out of isolation.  Schon also manages to briefly slip out a few times, leaving cryptic clues about the mystery.  There's also an element of personal danger to someone Ivo has fallen in love with, because Schon (convicted criminal) is attracted to her, too.  At the story's climax, Ivo must find a way to use Schon's intelligence without handing over control to him.

The synopsis I found for the book doesn't mention "Coventry" as the name given to Schon's isolation, but my memory thinks it's there.  The number of personalities in Ivo's head (two - Ivo and Schon) is also fewer than your description, but there are enough points of similarity that I think *Macroscope* might possibly be the book.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But the answer is "Set this house in order", proposed by John Rennie.

Comment: You've also got a lot of the plot wrong - Schon wasn't sentenced to isolation but put himself deliberately there to hide from the authorities running the experiment on the kids. Ivo is the only one in real danger because of Schon regains control, he will cease to exist. This is an important sub-plot in Macroscope but the main story is about this "snooping" technology and an intelligence-killing broadcast that limits access to the rest of the galaxy.